# How to understand $Re(z) + Im(z) = 2$ & $Re(z) - Im(z) = 0$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

So I got stuck on a question asking me to plot in $\mathbb{C}$ the following two expressions ($z \in \mathbb{C}$):
$$Re(z) + Im(z) = 2$$
$$Re(z) - Im(z) = 0$$

Now this should be easy enough...

If we set $z = x +iy$ the first equation should be:
$Re(x + iy) + Im(x +iy) = 2$ Which would give me: $x + y = 2$ and the line $y = - x + 2$
*Which is wrong...*

The same thing with the second equation:
$Re(x+iy) - Im(x+iy) = 0$ would give me: $x - y = 0$ and the line $y=x$
*Which is also wrong...*

Something obvious is missing from my understanding of this...

Comment: This should be correct,but you're only looking for the intersection of those 2 lines

Comment: Why do you think your results are wrong?

Comment: You are right, this is not wrong, I was not understanding the question properly. Thank you! I have been pulling my hair for a while on this question now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z=x+iy$.

According to your equations, $z$ is a point of both the lines $y=-x+2$ and $y=x$ so it's the intersection of the both! That's a linear system of two equations with two unknown numbers, if the two lines aren't parallel or same then $z$ is a single point which is the case. Find $z$ by fiding $x$ and $y$!

Comment: Thank you! This is indeed correct!

Comment: You're welcome!